# What is an efficient way to implement a high-update-rate GUI with AppKit?

Tags: swift, macos, performance, cocoa

We are trying to implement a utility which may display up to 100 level meters, updating (for example) 20 times a second. We are using NSLevelIndicator for this purpose.

The issue we are having is CPU usage is unacceptably high. I appreciate that we are trying to do 2000 updates per second, but from a rendering perspective this should be fairly trivial for a modern platform. Yet we are hitting ~30% usage just from this! This is going to become a bigger problem when we move to mobile platforms.

I've put together a simple example that demonstrates the issue with a single slider. This can easily hit 10% on my machine (and my colleague's) if the update rate is pushed to 100 updates per second, for a single slider! I appreciate that this is not an NSLevelIndicator but the effect is the same.

```
import Cocoa

class ViewController: NSViewController {
    
    var lastValue:Int = 0
    
    @IBOutlet weak var Slider: NSSlider!
    
    var timer:Timer? = nil

    func changeMeter ()
    {
        lastValue = lastValue + 1
        if (lastValue == 100)
        {
            lastValue = 0
        }
        
        self.Slider.integerValue = lastValue
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        timer = Timer.init(timeInterval: 0.02, repeats: true) { (timer) in
            self.changeMeter()
        }
        
        lastValue = 10;
        RunLoop.main.add(timer!, forMode: RunLoop.Mode.default)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }
}
```

My question: **is there a better way to do this?** I suspect that this is a misuse of the API (designed for infrequent user interactions) and that there may be a more efficient way to do this. We will be scaling this up further with even more high-frequency controls, so simply reducing the update rate is not really a sustainable option. Open to thoughts and suggestions! Thank you.

Comment: One obvious suggestion: if the `lastValue` has not changed, bail out.

Comment: @matt assume that it has changed :)

Comment: Are you creating 100 view controllers with 100 separate timers? I think you should be running a single timer to batch update your data. If you are updating close to the screen refresh rate kill any animations. It might be worth looking at GamplayKit or similar for 'game update loops' for something like this.